# How to use the complex analysis identity?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula, cauchy-principal-value

We have following identity in complex analysis. (Snider 8.5 prob 8).

$$\underset{\epsilon\rightarrow0^+}{lim}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0+i\epsilon}\,dx=P\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{f(x)}{x-x_0}\,dx-i\pi f(x_0)$$

When $f(x)=1$ is tranforms to,

$$\frac{1}{x-x_0+i\epsilon}=P\frac{1}{x-x_0}-i\pi\delta(x-x_0)$$

I can't figure out why this is happening? Is it because when $x=x_0$ integral equal to infinity?

I want to check whether my understanding is correct.

Comment: What is your source for the displayed identity after "tranforms to"?

Comment: Fundamentals of Complex Analysis with Applications to Engineering and Science Book by Arthur David Snider and E. B. Saff .. Section 8.5 Question 8

Comment: The authors take care to explain that the second identity in your post has no rigorous mathematical meaning as is, and that it should be interpreted as the first identity being true for every suitable function $f$. One can wonder why you see fit to annihilate their explanations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the first integral and complex version (replace $x$ with $z$) you must be aware that there exists a pole at $x_0+i\epsilon$. Typical way to evaluate a real integral using a complex contour uses a semicircle  with two end points on the real line and the line segment defined by the end points. First consider full circle and use Cauchy Residue integral then half circle gives $-i\pi f(x_0)$ (clockwise) as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. and the part on the real line gives $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)/(x-x_0)dx$. By P you mean principal value I guess.

Regarding the second part just take the derivative of the first identity with the integral w.r.t $x$. Remember that $1/(x-x_0)$ has a pole at $x=x_0$ so we should expect a Dirac delta impulse. Just recheck residues before your exams